# match the sequence between a word and the last occurding space

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy, regex-lookarounds

I am looking to extract specific set of characters matching after a particular word till the last space that occurs in the sequence.

Example:

```
FAILED on portal HTTP (10.1.1.1)
FAILED on portal TELNET 0 SSH (10.1.1.1)
```

I want the O/P to be:

```
HTTP
TELNET 0 SSH
```

Currently using the following RegEX and working on it:

```
.+((?<=portal)[^\s]]+
```

Will be helpful if anyone of you can help me out on this :)

**Updated from comment:**

Text:

```
1368028793000 10.3.1.4 CISCO X AUTHENTICATION:SESSION User authentication attempt FAILED on portal TELNET 0 SSH (10.1.2.8:64940)
```

Regex:

```
^(\d+).* (\S+\d) ([\w\s]+) (\w* ?AUTHENTICATION:SESSION) (.+) (([\w.]+):(\d+)).*
```

Typically the groups I would like to have from my sample string would be:

```
#1 - 1368028793000 
#2 - 10.3.1.4 
#3 - CISCO X 
#4 - AUTHENTICATION:SESSION 
#5 - User authentication attempt FAILED on portal 
#6 - TELNET 0 SSH 
#7 - 10.1.2.8 
#8 - 6940
```

Comment: Ok.. I will describe the whole thing that I am trying

Comment: Text: 1368028793000 10.3.1.4 CISCO X AUTHENTICATION:SESSION User authentication attempt FAILED on portal TELNET 0 SSH (10.1.2.8:64940)


Regex:  ^(\d+).* (\S+\d) ([\w\s]+) (\w* ?AUTHENTICATION:SESSION) (.+) \(([\w.]+):(\d+)\).*

Comment: Do you really want to capture all these groups? or only what there is after portal?

Comment: I have managed to capture all the groups... But I want to capture what is there after 'portal' in a separate group. be it HTTP, TELNET 0 SSH, FTP etc...

Comment: Could you explain what groups you want to keep, with their values according to your sample string?

Comment: Typically the groups I would like to have from my sample string would be 

#1 - 1368028793000
#2 - 10.3.1.4
#3 - CISCO X
#4 - AUTHENTICATION:SESSION
#5 - User authentication attempt FAILED on portal
#6 - TELNET 0 SSH
#7 - 10.1.2.8
#8 - 6940

Comment: Have a look at my revised answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All change according to new requirement.

Have a try with:

```
^(\d+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\w\s]+?)\s+(AUTHENTICATION:SESSION)\s+(.+?portal)\s(.+?)\(([\d.]+)(?::(\d+))?\)$
```

Here is a perl script that runs it:

```
my $re = qr/^(\d+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\w\s]+?)\s+(AUTHENTICATION:SESSION)\s+(.+?portal)\s(.+?)\(([\d.]+)(?::(\d+))?\)$/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @l = ($_ =~ $re);
    dump@l;
}
__DATA__
1368028793000 10.3.1.4 CISCO X AUTHENTICATION:SESSION User authentication attempt FAILED on portal HTTP (10.1.1.1)
1368028793000 10.3.1.4 CISCO X AUTHENTICATION:SESSION User authentication attempt FAILED on portal TELNET 0 SSH (10.1.2.8:64940)
```

**output:**

```
(
  1368028793000,
  "10.3.1.4",
  "CISCO X",
  "AUTHENTICATION:SESSION",
  "User authentication attempt FAILED on portal",
  "HTTP ",
  "10.1.1.1",
  undef,
)
(
  1368028793000,
  "10.3.1.4",
  "CISCO X",
  "AUTHENTICATION:SESSION",
  "User authentication attempt FAILED on portal",
  "TELNET 0 SSH ",
  "10.1.2.8",
  64940,
)
```

**regex explain:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(\d+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\w\s]+?)\s+(AUTHENTICATION:SESSION)\s+(.+?portal)\s(.+?)\(([\d.]+)(?::(\d+))?\)$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\d.]+                   any character of: digits (0-9), '.' (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\s]+?                 any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                             \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    AUTHENTICATION:SES       'AUTHENTICATION:SESSION'
    SION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    portal                   'portal'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \6:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \6
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \7:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\d.]+                   any character of: digits (0-9), '.' (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \7
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \8:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \8
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks.. But this one gives the below O/P

portal TELNET 0 SSH
(and)
TELNET 0 SSH

Comment: @Designerztouch: sorry i don't get you.

Comment: Ok. I have put exactly what I needed from what :) I hope it is clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Dude ! This works 100% for me ! :D Thank you very very much for a timely and great help. You saved my day...

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try this:

```
(?<=portal\s)(.+)\s\(
```

Note that you have a missing closing bracket `)` and a missing opening square bracket `[`, which I assume was a typo. And you need to escape the opening bracket which marks the start of the `(10.1.1.1)` bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
(?<=portal).+(?=\s)
```

`.+` is greedy so it would match till end and then backtrack if necessary..